# Why is this if command no syntax error and to what result does it evaluate?

Tags: python

I made a programming error in an algorithm which I didn't notice for a period of time. Doesn't matter the results were good and we wanted to implement this production in the productive system (model in python, productive system in c++).

So the first if statement in this algorithm should end the calculation if `c == 0` or `b == False`
Unfortunately the statement was programmed like this:

```
if c == 0 is not b:
    return
```

Instead of:

```
if c == 0 or not b:
    return
```

My question now is, why is the first if statement no syntax error? I don't see any logical statement this should evaluate? Can someone explain as what the python interpreter interpretes this statement?

To understand the behaviour I calculated the truth table:

```
c |   b   | result
-------------------
0 | False | True
0 | True  | True
1 | False | False
1 | True  | False
```

So it seems that python tests for `c == 0` and ignores the `is not b`, what ever this is meant to be. In my eyes it checks if the temporarily True or False statement `is not` the same object as `b`, what it never is, therefore we get the above resulting truth table. Is this thought correct?

Comment: `c == 0 is not b` is the same as `(c == 0) and (0 is not b)`. You can find it in the documentation: [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

Comment: Ah I got it, 0 is NEVER b and therefore always true